# How to set Realm when using OAuthWebSecurity for Google authentication request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-openid

So I recently ran into an issue where Google would return a different OpenId for users based on the machine they were logging in from. This SO post helped me figure out why it was happening: [Why does my OpenID app receive different Google OpenIDs from different client machines for the same user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780842/why-does-my-openid-app-receive-different-google-openids-from-different-client-ma)

My question is this. Is there anyway to set the realm when using OAuthWebSecurity in my MVC 4.5 app so that it is the same everytime regardless of what the url is for my app?

Thanks.

Comment: I would switch to Oauth2 where you can get an access token and then exchange it for user info, including her email. Email doesn't change depending on your app url. I am not sure if you can retrieve email with open id.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks for the comment. That is an option I have considered, however I was hoping to not have to rewrite the authentication part of my app just yet.

Comment: Fortunately these two do not differ fundamentally. Rather, you just redirect to a different resource and then consume the response in sligthly different way. But then, having the token, their api is open for you to automate (including the profile api).

Comment: What I ended up doing was adding a rewrite rule to web.config that did a permanent redirect to the domain for the app so if the user entered www.myapp.com they would get redirected to myapp.com and the Google OpenId API would get the same domain every time. This doesn't answer my question but it worked for me for now. I will rewrite to use DotNetOpenAuth in the future so I can use the OAuth2 API.